Received unregistered task of type '__main__.create_video'
I have task and celery worker in the same file,

from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    return celery


celery = make_celery(app)


@celery.task
def create_video(company_a, company_b, video_id):

I am getting the error Received unregistered task of type '_main_.create_video'.

@app.route('/create-video', methods=['POST'])
def create_video_req():
    data = request.json
    print(data)
    company_a= data.get('InputTexta')
    company_b=data.get('InputTextb')
    

    # Generate a mock video ID and status URL
    video_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    result = create_video.delay(company_a, company_b, video_id)
    return jsonify({"videoId": video_id}), 201

Celery worker shows the correct tasks
[tasks]
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . scripttovideoapp.create_video

Celery recieves it as main.create_video instead of scripttovideoapp.create_video
